# Is there a mapping between Books online ms-help:// and http://msdn.microsoft.com

Tags: sql-server, msdn

Often when I find an article in the SQL Server BOL I see that the article has an address of `ms-help://`.

but I can't forward this "uri" to a colleague who doesn't have the Sql Server BOL --- so the question is is there a consistent mapping between ms-help:// and http://msdn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN online changes at a different pace than your offline content. Ie. the mapping function may be valid today but invalid tomorrow. What I do I just search the topic title in msdn (using google site:msdn.microsoft.com of course, msdn search is just lame) and the post/mail the link.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, my answer would be to use the msdn for everything, unless you're personally offline and don't have access to it.

If you like using the MSHELP application, it is possible in the settings to make it use msdn online, rather than local content (this is the default if you don't bother installing the local docs anyway).

This means you always have the msdn link (even in the help application) and therefore can share it with your colleagues.

Comment: Yes sometimes we're offline and sometimes we're on.  Hence the question.  So I'm guessing that the answer is "no" there is no simple mapping to MSDN web site from BOL content

Comment: Pretty much.  Personally I'd set mine to go online, then offline just if I knew I was.  I've not tried it but I bet the help application has functionality that will go looking for local data if you're offline anyway.